# delete row from table with href

Tags: php, javascript, html, symfony

I want to delete a row in the table and also delete  the database using a href link but when I click on the link line will not delete
my table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
<tr>

<th> </th>
<th>Kpi</th>
<th>Criticity</th>
<th>Service</th>
<th>Condition Kpi</th>
<th>Condition 1</th>
<th>Condition 2</th>
<th>Condition 3</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>




{% for kpi in KPIs %}
<tr class="gradeU">
<td >{{kpi.getid}}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.kpi }}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.criticity}}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.service }}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.conditionkpi }}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.num1 }}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.num2 }}</td>
<td>{{ kpi.num3 }}</td>
<td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td>
<td value="{{kpi.getid}}"><a href="#" onclick="suppLigne(this.parentNode.parentNode)"> Supprimer </a>



</tr>
{% endfor %}


</tbody>
</table>
ma fonction javascript:
function suppLigne( ligne){
ligne.parentNode.removeChild( ligne);
}
```

I also tried with this function in my controller but still no good answer

```
    public function supprimerkpiAction()
{ 
        $session =$this->get('request')->getSession() ;
        $user_name = $session->get('user_name');


$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:Conditionalertes');
$id=$this->getRequest()->query->get('id');
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$uti=$repository->find($id);
                $em->remove($uti);
                $em->flush();

   $KPIs =  $repository->findAll();

      return $this->render('AdminBlogBundle:GestionKPI:supprimer.html.twig', array('user_name'=>$user_name,'KPIs'=>$KPIs));


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add action to delete "KPI" whatever it is call it `deleteAction`.
   2, Add Param id with the kpi id.
2. Make the named routing for that deleteAction and name it YourBundleKpiDelete. And add parameter to the route ex. `/kpi/delete/{id}`
3. Use the following code in your template:

   ```
   <td><a class="delete" href="{{ path('YourBundleKpiDelete', {'id':kpi.id} }}">Delete</a></td>
   ```
4. Your ready to go. Badum tss.